# Control CSS rotation animation: Get, set, start, stop

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to continuously rotate an HTML5 image or div using CSS3 animation effects.
Need the javascript to perform all of the basic functions related to this:

1) Set rotation speed of the image.

2) Get the current rotation value, in degrees.

3) Start and stop rotation.

If possible, please provide a working example of the html, css, js.  A js class would be lovely.
Thanks very much.

Comment: I have clarified.  I see nothing 'broad' or unanswerable about this question. A good answer was provided.  Being able to control CSS3 animation is a general-purpose issue that many people need. This question asks for the basic functions in one place (get, set, start, stop).  Putting each of these into a separate question would just mean that someone would have to piece it all together.  I expect that this question will be viewed quite a lot and be helpful to people.  It's already been helpful to me.  Closing it just prevents this.  Please re-open.  Thanks.

Comment: Note to moderators: This is a very good question and very good answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working example of some of the features that you asked for.
The features that are not present are pretty easy to implement.

It's a very basic implementation.

Please run it on codepen.io otherwise the stylesheet reference will not work.

http://codepen.io/chocobowings/full/qOOzry/

```js
//console.log(document.styleSheets[2]);
// find the right style sheet //
var rule = document.styleSheets[2].cssRules[1];
//console.log(rule);

function change(){
  // first remove the old rules //
rule.deleteRule("0%");
rule.deleteRule("100%");

var angle1 = "-360deg"
var angle2 = "720deg"
// then add new rules //
rule.appendRule("0% { border-radius:0%; transform: rotate("+ angle1 + ");}");
rule.appendRule("90% { border-radius:30%; transform: rotate("+ angle2 + ");}");
  
  // log the variable after the changes //
 // console.log(rule);
 
 // log the rules new text // 
// you can extract from the cssText any information that you need 
 // console.log(rule.cssRules[0].cssText);
 // console.log(rule.cssRules[1].cssText);
}
function get()
{
//console.log(document.styleSheets[2]);
var el = document.getElementById("a");
var st = window.getComputedStyle(el, null);
var tr = st.getPropertyValue("-webkit-transform") ||
         st.getPropertyValue("-moz-transform") ||
         st.getPropertyValue("-ms-transform") ||
         st.getPropertyValue("-o-transform") ||
         st.getPropertyValue("transform") ||
         "FAIL";

// With rotate(30deg)...
// matrix(0.866025, 0.5, -0.5, 0.866025, 0px, 0px)
console.log('Matrix: ' + tr);

// rotation matrix - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

var values = tr.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',');
var a = values[0];
var b = values[1];
var c = values[2];
var d = values[3];

var scale = Math.sqrt(a*a + b*b);

console.log('Scale: ' + scale);

// arc sin, convert from radians to degrees, round
var sin = b/scale;
// next line works for 30deg but not 130deg (returns 50);
// var angle = Math.round(Math.asin(sin) * (180/Math.PI));
var angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(b, a) * (180/Math.PI));

console.log('Rotate: ' + angle + 'deg');

}
```

```css
.a {
  background-color: #344565;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  left:30vw;
  top: 30vh;
  animation: move 20s infinite;
}
@keyframes move {
  0% {
    border-radius:0%;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
     100% {
    border-radius:30%;
    transform: rotate(-720deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="change()">Change Values</button>
<button onclick="get()">Get Angle</button>
<div class="a" id="a">
  </div>
```

Comment: Using this code, how is it possible to get what the current rotation angle is?  This is actually the most important part.  Thanks.

Comment: I updated the code with a function get() to get the angle, scale and matrix of the current animation.

Comment: Thanks.  Fantastic.  I know that this is something that a lot of people need to do, so I hope that they'll find this question and your code helpful.  Thanks again.

Comment: No problem I am happy to help. If you feel that your question has been answered please mark it as answered.

Comment: I do feel that it has been answered, with a lovely answer, and I think it would be a very helpful question to plenty of other people.  Irksome that it has been closed.  If you can reverse this, I think that'd be a community service.  In any case, it helped me, so thanks!

Comment: This is nice! Thank you FP